# Can we have the ExtendedFloatingActionButton width match parent when expanded?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I want `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` to have width match parent. currently it only sets width according to the text length.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [`1.2.0-alpha05`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/55200c3a8f18604a723c7ad6ab48fb9ec03391ba) you can define in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   ..>
```

and the fab looks like:

[image]

However when you expand the same button the width becomes `WRAP_CONTENT` and you can't change it.

[image]